# jRuby, gems with C extensions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

Does anyone has the same error with jRuby? When I trying to install gem with C extension I have the next error:

> gem install serialport Building native extensions.  This could take a
>   while... ERROR:  Error installing serialport:     ERROR: Failed to build
>   gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     /home/username/.rvm/rubies/jruby-head/bin/jruby extconf.rb NotImplementedError: C > extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.
> ```
>
> (root) at
>   /home/username/.rvm/rubies/jruby-head/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
>   require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1021    (root) at
>   /home/username/.rvm/rubies/jruby-head/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
>   (root) at extconf.rb:1

Any arguments declared in errors explanation does not give any success...

**Info about installed jruby version:**
jruby 1.7.0.preview2.dev (1.9.3p203) 2012-08-05 22cd6f9 on Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.7.0_05-b05 [linux-i386]

**Platform:** Linux

**Gem:** serialport

Comment: It says: "Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable". Did you do that?

Comment: Did you try all of them?

Comment: can you write an example for installing "serialport" gem?

Comment: C extension support for JRuby is buggy and deprecated. You aren't likely to get what you want with C extensions. The best option would be to find a Java library that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As echristopherson as put it C extension support for JRuby is deprecated. In most gems you should find the Java specific version in [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/) or a healthy alternative lyiing around in Github. I do not recommend you to try an hack the gem to work with jruby as it will be a world of pain...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the rs232 gem?  It may have jruby support, as the ffi gem it depends on has jruby support.  https://rubygems.org/gems/rs232