# How to enable C extensions error in Jruby?

Tags: jruby

I am getting the following error and dont know how to solve this.          Can someone simplify this process?

My Jruby is installed in

> C:/jruby-1.7.13/bin

my project is in

> C:/Users/myname/downloads/projectdirectory

The error is when I do

```
bundle install

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

c:/jruby-1.7.13/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb
  NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS.

    (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
    require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065
    (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
    (root) at extconf.rb:2


    Gem files will remain installed in c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pg-0.17.0 for inspection.
    Results logged to c:/jruby-1.7.13/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pg-0.17.0/ext/gem_make.out
     An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
     Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable C extension support in jRuby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795942/how-to-enable-c-extension-support-in-jruby)

Answer (score 0):

C- extensions are not really supported in JRuby and were actually dropped in the 1.7.x line ...

thus despite the message mentioning `-Xcext.enabled=true` won't help you!

since it's **pg** you're trying, there's a jruby alternative that uses a Java API instead of C **pg_jruby**, alternatively if you're using active-record look for **activerecord-jdbc-adapter** + **jdbc-postgres**

Comment: I installed pg_jruby using "gem install pg_jruby" but still getting the same error.

Comment: In general whenever I try to install a gem that involves a native extension throws the same error. Is there a solution that can enable all extensions installation?