# JRuby middleman server with watch on windows

Tags: windows, server, jruby, watch, middleman

I'm trying to run middleman as server from JRuby, as part of my Java project components to build the project UI. The thing is that when adding the wdm watching dependency on JRuby, to watch files on Windows, it fails to add that gem because of:

```
NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS.
```

If I don't add the wdm gem, then middleman servers starts, but is not aware of file changes on my computer, therefore there is no watching.

I've also tried to make it work by following the guidelines on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795942/how-to-enable-c-extension-support-in-jruby), but it doesn't work either. When attempting that approach, the following errors happens:

```
C:/jruby-1.7.23/bin/jruby.exe -r C:\jruby-1.7.23\lib\ruby\gems\shared\gems\wdm-0.1.1\ext\wdm\siteconf20151203-9936-15la6zz.rb extconf.rb
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
C:/jruby-1.7.23/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:14: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at C:/jruby-1.7.23/lib/native/include/ruby/ruby.h
```

What can I do? Please help

Comment: Have you found anything about passing `-Xcext.enabled=true`?

Comment: Yes, couldn't make that work either. Seems jruby doesn't support c extension compilation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable C extension support in jRuby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795942/how-to-enable-c-extension-support-in-jruby)

Comment: I think your problem is the same of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15795942/641451) - and there's an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly that didn't work... I added the results of that process to the question.